# Generar thumbnail de videos en Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, djangorestframework

Estoy implementando thumbnail, el flujo seria:

- Agregar un video (Ya esta hecho)
- Una vez agregado el video generar un thumbnail y guardarlo en el modelo

Estoy tratando de implementar [MoviePy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204317/moviepy-error-the-file-tmp-testvideo-mp4-could-not-be-found-please-check-tha), sin embargo no entiendo del todo como deberia hacer la implementacion para que al momento de subir el video lo detecte y genere el thumbnail.

No tengo claro cual es la mejor forma, si hacerlo en el modelo o hacerlo en la vista.

Me base en estas preguntas para formular codigo, aunque mi duda sigue presente, ya que soy bastante nuevo en Django:

[referencia moviePy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204317/moviepy-error-the-file-tmp-testvideo-mp4-could-not-be-found-please-check-tha)

Modelo:

```
def path_and_rename(obj, filename):
ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
path = 'AppVideos/'

filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
return os.path.join(path, filename)

class videosApp(FieldDefaultsAbstracts):

filename = models.FileField(
    upload_to=path_and_rename,
    blank=False,
    validators=[validate_file_extension]
)
thumbnail = models.FileField(
    blank=False,
    null=True
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.filename.delete()
    super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-id']

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

View:

```
class VideosApp(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
model = models.videosApp
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
serializer_class = serializers.VideoAppDetailSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.model.objects.all()
    return self.filter(queryset)

def filter(self, queryset):
    kwargs = self.request.GET
    name = kwargs.get('name', None)
    user = kwargs.get('user',None)
    queryset = queryset.filter(
        # owner=self.request.user,
        is_active=True
    )
    if name:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            name__icontains=name
        )
    if user:
        queryset= queryset.filter(
            user__id=user
        )    
    return queryset

    print(settings.AWS_ENABLE)
    print(type(settings.AWS_ENABLE))
    if settings.AWS_ENABLE:
        print('Enabled S3')
    else:
        print('not enabled S3')

    return queryset

def perform_create(self, request, serializer):
    item = serializer.save(
        owner=self.request.user,
        is_active=True
    )
    return item

def perform_update(self, serializer):

    serializer.save()
    return Response({'message': 'Updated data'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def perform_destroy(self, instance):
    instance.is_active = False
    instance.save()
    return Response({'message': 'User Deleted'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```